# execute async functions in fixed order javascript

Tags: javascript, function, async-await

I've got **3 functions** and i want to **execute them in a fixed order (f1, f2, f3)**. I've tried async await and aswell promises, the first approach didn't work and the second i didn't understand i guess.

The first function pushes local paths to an array named 'jsons', the second function pushes the data from the paths to an array named 'profile' and the third function sends the array 'profile' to a url.
I'm aware that this might not be the securest way, but it's just a little project to understand js better.

```
function visualroute() { 

  const jsons = [];
  const profile = [];

  router.get('/user', verify, async (req, res) => {//here i want the data to be sent to
    
    //Push array jsons
    const checker = async function (){
      sqldb.query(`SELECT * FROM ${username}`, (error, result) =>{
      console.log('1');
        if(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
        if( result.length == 0 ) {
          console.log('User does not have initiated a db yet');
          return res.render('user/index', {
            message: 'No data added to db yet'
          });
        } else {
          try{        
            //for loop to push the required info into jsons[]
            for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
              jsons.push(`../public/jsonsheets/${result[i].infoticker}.json`);
            }
            console.log(jsons);
          } catch(err){
            throw err;
          } 
        };//else end
      });//checker end
    }

    //push array profile
    const jsonreader = async function() {
      console.log('2');
      for(i=0; i<jsons.lenght; i++){
        //Check if path exists
        try {
          fs.access(`public/jsonsheets/${jsons[i]}`, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Does not exist');
              return
            }
            console.log('Exists');

            //exists: read it into profile[]
            fs.readFile(`public/jsonsheets/${jsons[i]}`, (err, data) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              let userdata = JSON.parse(data);

              profile.push(userdata);
              
            });
          })
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }//for loop end
      
      console.log(profile);
    }

    // send data to url
    const finalsender = async function() {
      console.log('3');
      res.send(
        profile
      );
    }  
    
    async function quefunction(){
      await checker();
      await jsonreader();
      await finalsender();
    }

    quefunction();
    
  }); //route end
}; //visualroute end

visualroute();
```

my output: 2, 3, 1 and like so an empty array on the receiving url.

Comment: Can you add the omitted code inside the checker and jsonreader functions, probably that's where the problem originates

Comment: The order is correct for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ewbtc2Lr/

Comment: Hi Bastian, hi Chris, thank you for your quick response! I just edited my post and inserted the stuff from the functions.

Comment: `await f(); await g(); await h();` _does_ executes them sequentially.

Comment: You need to promisify those asynchronous functions and their callbacks, otherwise `async` and `await` does nothing. The basic idea is: 1) you have a Promise 2) you want to run more code, but only after the Promise resolves, so you `await` it 3) you cannot use `await` in sync context, so you move it inside an `async` function. Give me a few minutes and I'll show you example code.

Comment: awesome Chris! I was able to fix a few issues with my code aswell in the meantime, so that the only reason it's not running right now is the order of the functions executed. Looking forward to the example code.

Comment: Here's the example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ewbtc2Lr/ (I hope it's easy to understand, this can be pretty daunting if you've never used promises :)

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, first and second function needs to return promise.
because their body contains async function(eg db.query, and fs.access) and the only way to return result(settle down result) in async function is calling resolve().

refer to below.

```
const jsons = [];
const profile = [];

router.get('/user', verify, async (req, res) => {//here i want the data to be sent to
  
  //Push array jsons
  const checker = async function (){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // return Promise
        sqldb.query(`SELECT * FROM ${username}`, (error, result) =>{
            // console.log('1');
              if(error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error); // reject here to quit processing
              }
              if( result.length == 0 ) {
                console.log('User does not have initiated a db yet');
                res.render('user/index', {
                  message: 'No data added to db yet'
                });
                reject('no user invited'); // no need to process more
              } else {
                try{        
                  //for loop to push the required info into jsons[]
                  for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                    jsons.push(`../public/jsonsheets/${result[i].infoticker}.json`);
                  }
                  console.log(jsons);
                  console.log(1)
                  resolve(); // resolve and then next function call starts.
                } catch(err){
                  //throw err;
                  reject(err);
                } 
              };//else end
            });//checker end
    })

  }

  //push array profile
  const jsonreader = async function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('2');
        for(i=0; i<jsons.lenght; i++){
          //Check if path exists
          try {
            fs.access(`public/jsonsheets/${jsons[i]}`, fs.F_OK, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Does not exist');
                reject(err);
              }
              console.log('Exists');
  
              //exists: read it into profile[]
              fs.readFile(`public/jsonsheets/${jsons[i]}`, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                let userdata = JSON.parse(data);
                profile.push(userdata);
                resolve();                    
              });
            })
          } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
          }
        }//for loop end
    })        
  }

  // send data to url
  const finalsender = async function() {
    console.log('3');
    res.send(
      profile
    );
  }  
  
  async function quefunction(){
    try {
        await checker();
        await jsonreader();
        await finalsender();
    } catch(err) {
        // all reject function call will jump to here
        console.error(err);
    }

  }

  quefunction();
  
 }); //route end
}; //visualroute end

visualroute();
```